# How do i download a file from Website that loaded before clicking

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, download

I'm trying to download files from a website but whenever I see Network it makes a request to `..te-guitar.com/tab/download?id={}&session_id=` which means it downloading from a file from this URL but it seems like it loaded data with any other URL when the button is clicked then it make another request which doesn't contain any file.
This is website : https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/ghost/kaisarion-guitar-pro-4104691

[image: Application Tab Inspect Tools]

This is how the `form` of HTML looks like for downloading

````
<form action="https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/download">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="4104691">
<input type="hidden" name="session_id">
<div class="Z_7o4"><span class="wJEcW">Click the button to download “Kaisarion” Guitar Pro tab</span>
<button type="submit" class="rPQkl yDkT4 IxFbd exTWY lTEpj qOnLe">
<span class="KNVWh _sWeD">DOWNLOAD Guitar Pro TAB</span></button>
</div>
</form>```
````

Comment: it can use JavaScript to run different code.

Comment: this page needs to login to download it. And Python code has also login to download it.

Comment: `<form>` is rather for sending data to server. And normally it would reload page but using `JavaScript` it can send it and get data without reloading page - and it may use different URL for this.

Comment: Is there any way to find from which URL it does loading file content? I have edited my question please have it as I have found so many `.wav` files?

Comment: maybe try all urls which you found in DevTools and see which one gives you data.

Comment: your image doesn't show tab `networks` but local stores (databases on your computer). Page can download some data and keep locally and later it can send you data from local storage - and this needs JavaScript. Eventually you can check folder with browser and search files `.sqlite` (with databases) - maybe one of them will have this file.

Comment: I would like to with Python, Can please help me with this?

Comment: Python has standard module `sqlite3` so you can read database using Python. But I would first check all urls from `networks` instead of looking at `application`

Comment: Thanks For Your Help! but seems like it was correct URL only headers were missed to get file